# Send data from HTML form to server using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I'm trying to take the input from an HTML form and send it to the server to be added to a sqlite database. I'm struggling a little with the implementation and am wondering if I am on the right path or need to completely change course.

Currently when I click the button it redirects to the aspx page which displays another form and the data that I put in there will be added to the database, but I would like to be able to just send the data from the html page.

Here is what I've got for the HTML form where I'm letting the user input the data.

```
<form method="POST" action="players.aspx">
     <input type="text"  name="playername" id="playername" placeholder="Player"/> 
     <input type="text" name="points" id="points" placeholder="Points" />
     <input type="text" name="steals" id="steals" placeholder="Steals" />
     <input type="text" name="blocks" id="blocks" placeholder="Blocks" /> 
     <input type="text" name="assists" id="assists" placeholder="Assists" />
     <input type="text" name="mpg" id="mpg" placeholder="MPG" /> 
     <input type="text" name="shotpct" id="shotpct" placeholder="Shot %" />
     <input type="text" name="threepct" id="3pct" placeholder="3 %" /> 
     <input type="submit" value="add player" id="addbtn" name="addbtn" />
     </form>
```

Here's my aspx file, this what I have come up with after some googling

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="playername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox  ID="points" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:TextBox ID="steals" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox  ID="blocks" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:TextBox ID="assists" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox  ID="mpg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:TextBox ID="shotpct" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox  ID="threepct" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="addbtn" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And finally here is my method in the aspx.cs file for loading the data into the database.

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NBAPlayer player = new NBAPlayer();
            player.PlayerName = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["playername"]);//playername.Text;
            player.Points = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["points"]));
            player.Steals = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["steals"]));
            player.Blocks = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["blocks"]));
            player.Assists = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["assists"]));
            player.MPG = Convert.ToInt32(String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["mpg"]));
            player.ShootingPercentage = Convert.ToSingle(String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["shotpct"]));
            player.ThreePointPercentage = Convert.ToSingle(String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["threepct"]));

            NBAPlayerRepository players = new NBAPlayerRepository();
            players.AddRecord(player);
            loadTable();
        }
```

Comment: why dont send that data with ajax to a webservice?

Comment: @giammin so I can send the form data with ajax to that method? I'm kinda new to this stuff so I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: you make an ajax call from the html form to a webservice on your server without the need to have an aspx page

Comment: @giammin ah that makes sense, I was trying to avoid the aspx page. Thanks!

Comment: Look into [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) if you're going to be doing a lot of posting this type of thing. Otherwise I recommend using a `.ashx` generic handler for ad hoc handling of posted data.

Comment: @mason so using Web API would be better if I wanted to frequently update the database with new data?

Comment: Using Web API would be better if this pattern of posting data to the server via AJAX is one you plan to commonly use in your application.

Comment: @mason I'm just kind of teaching myself this stuff by building something so what I'm trying to create is an html page that lists players and can add, update, and delete those same players.Right now I'm using jQuery datatables to pull in the data from a JSON file which I created from a datatable object. Right now I overwrite the JSON file everytime there is a change to the database. Probably not the best way to do it. Would a Web API help me streamline this whole process?

Comment: Probably so. Web API is a common way of exposing REST style services in ASP.NET.

Comment: @mason Alright I'll look into that. Thanks!